# How to send an Asynchronous POST request with a parameter in android?

Tags: java, android, post, android-asynctask, httprequest

so I have to send an asynchronous POST request to a php sever. With a parameter “Password” and a value of “EGOT”. If successful it will return a response and it should display how long it took. Now I know I have to use asyncTask but how I never done this before in android and some direction on how to start or what to do would be nice. Please help me out. My code is the following. This is what I got so far

```
     public class PingServerActivity extends Activity {

     private Button btn6;
    //private EditText value;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ping_server);

    btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_6);
    //value = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textV5);

    pingButton();

}

public void pingButton() {

    btn6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // this button would send the request to the server
            new PingPostTask().execute();

        }
    });

}

private class PingPostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        postData(params[2]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //display result

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Request Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    public void postData(String Password) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ec2-54-243-205-92.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Test/ping.php");

                    try {
                        // Add your data
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EGOT", Password));
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                        // Execute HTTP Post Request
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ping_server, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: You should use your pingButton() method in your onCreate,or nothing will occur.

Comment: @tianwei i updated the code but im still getting error with the AsyncTask.

Comment: You start your asyncTask with no arguments by "new PingPostTask().execute();"  and then get argument by "postData(params[2]);". So of course you got errors.You should study how to use asyncTask first(how to post and use its arguments).